# Do SharePoint bookmarks require a mySite?

Tags: sharepoint, profile, hyperlink, bookmarks, mysite

We want to try to prevent using a mySite and just use the profile of SharePoint 2010.  However, we want the user to store bookmarks (or links)- does this mean they need to have a mySite?  Is this possible with just a profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting- it looks like it can be in both places for SharePoint 2010...
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=74
Thanks Laura Rogers!